# Cassandra - Reading from Map<int, int> to Dictionary<Type, int> with enum

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax

Trying to figure out the best/simple/effective way to read from cassandra table, defined as a MAP into a c# DTO object, that is a dictionary with a key defined has an enumerator.

I figured a way to map from int to enum, by using the WithDbType() in the mapping. Although, given this is in a dictionary, cannot figure out to map it out.

Cassandra design:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (
    id INT,
    name TEXT,
    my_dictionary MAP<INT, INT>,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

DTO:

```
public class MyTableObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<EnumType, int> MyDictionary { get; set; }
}
```

ENUM:

```
public enum EnumType
{
   None = 0,
   SelectionOne = 1
}
```

C# Driver Mapper:

```
For<>(MyTableObject)
    .TableName("my_table")
    .PartitionKey("id")
    .Column(u => u.Id, cm => cm.WithName("id"))
    .Column(u => u.Name, cm => cm.WithName("name"))
    .Column(u => u.MerchantId, cm => cm.WithName("merchant_id"))

    .Column(p => p.MyDictionary, cm => cm.WithName("my_dictionary"))

    .ExplicitColumns();
}
```

Any help with setting up this line?

```
.Column(p => p.MyDictionary, cm => cm.WithName("my_dictionary"))
```

Comment: As a side note, I'm trying to avoid the creation of a cassandra model, like "MyTableObjectCassandra" and have a property of Dictionary<int, int>, then mapping that into the MyTableObject with a cast to EnumType from the int.